# Spine 2D Animation with Equippable Items Dynamically at Runtime

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation, spine

I am attempting to make a rigged animated character using Spine but this "base" character will be able to pick up items and equip them such as jackets, helmets, etc. This will be a 2D top-down game and will include a ton of different gear options. Also, characters will be able to choose a base character with different skin colors, hairstyles, etc... I would almost like it to be a base character animation (skeleton) and you add gear (like a jacket) on top of the skeleton dynamically in the game so it moves with it.

I have tried Skinning but I would rather not have to create every type of variation for each possible gear outcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into using the [SpriteLibrary and SpriteResolver classes from the 2D Animation package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@3.0/api/UnityEngine.Experimental.U2D.Animation.html) to handle swapping between the different possible equipment sprites?

Comment: Awesome! You’re a hero didn’t think of using unitys built in animation :P thanks!

Comment: If that solved your problem, it would be great to post an answer detailing how you used it, to help future users trying to do something similar.

Comment: I am working on a full build of it so I can share my use case. Don't want to mislead anyone before I get a deeper dive.